# how to convert str- value into -int value in more optimal way using pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am having a table which contains some values like this,

```
 a  b
s1  10
s2  12-
s3  13
s4  1-
s5  11
```

In this table val- indicates -val, i.e, **12- means -12**

I want to convert to this form

```
 a  b
s1  10
s2  -12
s3  13
s4  -1
s5  11
```

how to convert this column b as integer column.

so far I tried,

```
mask=df['b'].str.endswith('-')
df.loc[mask,'b']=df['b'].str.rstrip('-').astype(int)*(-1)
```

I can get a required result, but I am eagerly searching for Is there any other most optimal solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preferred Answer**

```
df.assign(b=df.b.str.replace('(.+)-', r'-\1').astype(int))

    a    b
0  s1   10
1  s2  -12
2  s3   13
3  s4   -1
4  s5   11
```

---

**Attempt at a Fast Answer**
Using list comprehension

```
df.loc[:, 'b'] = pd.to_numeric(
    [x[-1] + x[:-1] if x.endswith('-') else x for x in df.b.values.tolist()]
)
df

    a    b
0  s1   10
1  s2  -12
2  s3   13
3  s4   -1
4  s5   11
```

---

**Messing Around Answer**

```
mask = df.b.str.endswith('-')
df.loc[mask, 'b'] = (lambda s: s.str[-1].str.cat(s.str[:-1]))(df.b[mask])
df.b = df.b.astype(int)
df

    a    b
0  s1   10
1  s2  -12
2  s3   13
3  s4   -1
4  s5   11
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `str.replace`:

```
b = df.b.str.replace(r'(\d+)-', r'-\1')
print(b)
0     10
1    -12
2     13
3     -1
4     11
Name: b, dtype: object
```

You'd assign the result back, as so:

```
df['b'] = b.astype(int) # or .astype(float)
```

---

As [piRSquared suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46598939/how-to-convert-str-value-into-int-value-in-more-optimal-way-using-pandas/46598958?noredirect=1#comment80149908_46598958), you can use `df.replace` in a similar fashion, setting the `regex` switch to `True`:

```
df = df.replace(dict(b={'(\d+)-': r'-\1'}), regex=True)
df.b = df.b.astype(float)
print(df)
    a    b
0  s1   10
1  s2  -12
2  s3   13
3  s4   -1
4  s5   11
```

Thank you!

Comment: Since you went the replace route... `df.replace(dict(b={'(\d+)-': r'-\1'}), regex=True)`